# Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled error on imported module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm building an npm package that includes one react component as part of it. I originally developed the package as just a subfolder of the react app I was testing it on and it was all working. Now that I've extracted the code and turned it into it's own package, when I try to import it and build the react project it receives the error:

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled
...
Add @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yd) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

When I run build on the extracted package itself it builds with no issues, it's only when I try and incorporate it into the other project that it has issues. I've tried many of the other solutions from other threads with no luck.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-tracing-project",
  "version": "1.0.9",
  "description": "tracing and instrumentation for react projects",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "docs"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build:dev": "webpack --mode=development",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.13.13",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@opentelemetry/context-zone": "^0.19.0",
    "@opentelemetry/exporter-collector": "^0.19.0",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation": "^0.19.0",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-document-load": "^0.16.0",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fetch": "^0.19.0",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-user-interaction": "^0.16.0",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-xml-http-request": "^0.19.0",
    "@opentelemetry/plugin-react-load": "^0.16.0",
    "@opentelemetry/tracing": "^0.19.0",
    "@opentelemetry/web": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "@webpack-cli/generators": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "rollup": "^2.50.4",
    "webpack": "^5.38.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets:[
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
          {
            "loose": true
          }
        ]
      ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
// Generated using webpack-cli https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli

const path = require("path");

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == "production";

const config = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    // Add your plugins here
    // Learn more about plugins from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },

      // Add your rules for custom modules here
      // Learn more about loaders from https://webpack.js.org/loaders/
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = () => {
  if (isProduction) {
    config.mode = "production";
  } else {
    config.mode = "development";
  }
  return config;
};
```

Comment: "when I try to import it and build the react project it receives the error" - Where does it report the problem to be? How are things imported? Did you check the file that webpack has produced in your `dist` folder? Does it contain any `jsx`?

Comment: It has one line of jsx in the project and thats where it reports the problem. If I remove that line from the code, the import and other functions work fine.
The import is const Tracer = require('my-tracing-project') and then in the code I call Tracer.wrapper - the function with the jsx.
The main file in the dist folder doesn't look like it has jsx in it - I just searched for the line of jsx thats in the actual code and it came up with nothing, not sure how else to check. @Domi

Comment: The biggest issue that people face with these sorts of bundling and Webpack issues is having to learn about module resolution. Your line `require('my-tracing-project')` - how does it resolve that? Is it prefixed with a module name or a relative path? Make sure its pointing to the right file. Make sure your webpack output file (the one in  the `dist` folder) actually got transpiled correctly (and yes that might mean learning how to read webpack output files). Make sure you build in development mode for this exercise.

Comment: It is the module name not a relative path and it works for use with the other functions in the module and in the same file so I thought it was safe to assume it was pointing to the correct place. I also thought it was safe to assume webpack was transpiling it correctly because I initially got the same error when I started bundling it with webpack on the module itself but adding the babel react preset solved it there, so it seemed to me that it is being transpilied correctly.

Comment: also when I change the imports so that it imports the functions directly ```import wrapper from 'my-tracing-project'``` it still gets the same error.